# How to execute code written in codemirror textarea?

Tags: codemirror

I have written a basic code in CodeMirror's textarea and now facing problem in executing the code written.

Below is the HTML part:

```
       <form id="preview-form" method="post" action="<?php echo 
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

        <textarea class="codemirror-textarea" name="preview-form-comment" 
        id="preview-form-comment">
            #include<stdio.h>
            int main()
            {
                printf("Hello World!!");

            }
        </textarea>

        <input type="test" name="testID" id="testID" value="aqsa shahid">

        <br>

        <input type="submit" name="preview-form-submit" id="preview-form-
        submit" value="Submit" onclick="test();">


        </form> 

        <div id="preview-comment"></div>
```

This is the function to execute code.

```
        function test() {
        //code goes here
        alert(document.getElementById("preview-form-comment").value);        

        var code = $(".codemirror-textarea")[0];
        var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code, {
        lineNumbers: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        mode: "text/x-csrc",
        theme: "dracula"

        });
        CodeMirror.runMode(document.getElementById("preview-form-
        comment").value, "text/x-csrc", document.getElementById('preview-
        comment')); };
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you probably solved this and it's old, but i will put this in case someone else is looking for the answer

i solved this using an iframe then in js

```
iframe.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(new_textarea.value)
```

and it worked for me .

Answer (score -1):

You probably should use a second textarea. Look at this code:

```
// on and off handler
CodemirrorInstance.on('change',function(e){
  // get value from instance
  new_textarea.value = e.getValue();
});
```

I could not test my code yet so I'm not sure if if will work.

Greetings.

Comment: I have tried using the above but it just nor run. Can you show me with an example as how to run the code just like "Try it" in w3schools. TIA